# Why does this piece of code work and the other doesn't? (pointers and linked lists)

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault, nodes

I am developing a simple game in C using SDL, and I need to make a linked list to store the bullets the player can shoot.

I tried two things:

```
typedef struct{
  SDL_Rect *bullet_sprite; // sprite of the bullet
  struct Bullet *next_bullet; 
} Bullet;

Bullet bullets; // here I initialized bullets
```

After creating an object called `bullets`, which will be used to store the bullets, here I created a void called `shoot()` which simply creates another bullet and stores it in the `*next_bullet`:

```
void shoot(Player *player){
  Bullet new_bullet;
  SDL_Rect rectangle = {player->x, player->y, BULLET_WIDTH, BULLET_HEIGHT};

  new_bullet.bullet_sprite = &rectangle;
  new_bullet.next_bullet = NULL;

  if(!player->n_of_bullets){
    bullets = new_bullet;
    printf("first bullet\n");
  }
  else{
    new_bullet.next_bullet = &bullets;
    bullets = new_bullet;
    printf("another bullet\n");
  }

  player->n_of_bullets++;
}
```

However, when the player shoots, a segmentation fault is created. (Why?)

When I change my code to:

```
typedef struct{
  SDL_Rect *bullet_sprite;
  struct Bullet *next_bullet;
} Bullet;

Bullet *bullets = NULL;
```

and `shoot()` to:

```
  Bullet *new_bullet = malloc(sizeof(Bullet));
  SDL_Rect rectangle = {player->x, player->y, BULLET_WIDTH, BULLET_HEIGHT};

  new_bullet->bullet_sprite = &rectangle;
  new_bullet->next_bullet = NULL;

  if(!player->n_of_bullets){
    bullets = new_bullet;
    printf("first bullet\n");
  }
  else{
    new_bullet->next_bullet = bullets;
    bullets = new_bullet;
    printf("another bullet\n");
  }

  player->n_of_bullets++;
```

it seems to work just fine.
I'm just wondering why that is. Can someone point out my mistakes and why a Segmentation Fault is given in the first example?

Comment: You need to understand that local variables become unavailable after a function returns, so any pointers to local storage become invalid. That's true of both `new_bullet` and `rectangle`. So the version that you believe "works just fine" in fact does not, since your pointer `bullet_sprite`, which is set to the address of the local variable `rectangle`, is invalid as soon as the function returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first version of the `shoot()` function, the `new_bullet` structure is allocated by default in the **stack** memory. That means that when leaving the function, this memory section will be freed and used for other purpose. I think the problem is here: you relocates the `bullets` struct at the `new_bullet` address which should be only used inside this function.

The 2nd version of `shoot()` is correct since `malloc()` will allocate new variables in the **heap** memory and won't be freed when leaving the function.

By the way, you might use `free()` each time you don't need a bullet anymore. Because for now your program allocates a new struct in memory each time your gunner shoots but never releases them.

I hope it could help you.

Comment: Nit ... "the new_bullet structure has **automatic storage duration** with storage created within the **function stack**." and ".. this memory section (the function stack) will be **released for reuse** on function return and any reference to variables in that memory region after return invokes *Undefined Behavior*.